# (Leetcode) Valid parentheses

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, balanced-delimiters

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/) -

> *Given a string containing just the characters `'('`, `')'`, `'{'`, `'}'`, `'['` and `']'`, determine if the input string is valid.*
>
> *An input string is valid if -*
>
> - *Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.*
> - *Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.*
>
> *Note that an empty string is also considered valid.*
>
> ***Example 1 -***
>
> ```
> Input: "()"
> Output: True
> ```
>
> ***Example 2 -***
>
> ```
> Input: "()[]{}"
> Output: True
> ```
>
> ***Example 3 -***
>
> ```
> Input: "(]"
> Output: False
> ```
>
> ***Example 4 -***
>
> ```
> Input: "([)]"
> Output: False
> ```
>
> ***Example 5 -***
>
> ```
> Input: "{[]}"
> Output: True
> ```

---

Here is my solution to this challenge -

```
def is_valid(s):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return True
    parentheses = ['()', '[]', '{}']
    flag = False
    while len(s) > 0:
        i = 0
        while i < 3:
            if parentheses[i] in s:
                s = s.replace(parentheses[i], '')
                i = 0
                flag = True
            else:
                i += 1
        if len(s) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            flag = False
            break
    return False
```

So I would like to know whether I could improve performance and make my code shorter.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using flags? I removed the flags and it still seems to work, unless I made a mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a performance suggestion, but you can make use of the fact that an empty collection is Falsey.

```
if len(s) == 0:
```

Is functionally the same as just:

```
if not s:
```

And similarly,

```
while len(s) > 0:
```

Can be just:

```
while s:
```

[Relevant PEP entry](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51) (search for "For sequences" under the linked heading).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really helped a lot. I never realized this. Thanks for pointing this out. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code shorter and much faster by using `stack` -

> *Stack works on the principle of \$“\$Last-in, first-out \$”\$. Also, the inbuilt functions in Python make the code short and simple. To add an
>   item to the top of the list, i.e., to push an item, we use the
>   **`append()`** function and to pop out an element we use the **`pop()`** function. These functions work quite efficiently and fast in end operations.*

Here's a visual representation -

> [image]

<sup><sup>Source - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-data-structure/</sup></sup>

Here's a shorter and faster version of your program using `stack` -

```
def is_valid(s):
    stack = []
    mapping = {
        ")" : "(",
        "}" : "{",
        "]" : "["
    }

    if len(s) != 0: 
        for char in s: 
            if char in mapping: 
                if len(stack) == 0: 
                    return False
                else: 
                    top_element = stack.pop() 
                    if top_element != mapping[char]:
                        return False
            else:
                stack.append(char)
        return len(stack) == 0
    return True
```

Let's compare Leetcode timings (76 test cases) -

Your Leetcode result -

[image]

---

Leetcode result for `stack` solution (76 test cases) -

[image]

Also, you don't need *any* `flag` here (Thanks to @moondra for pointing it out) -

```
parentheses = ['()', '[]', '{}']
flag = False
while len(s) > 0:
     # rest of the code
```

Or here -

```
s = s.replace(parentheses[i], '')
i = 0
flag = True
```

Or here -

```
    else:
        flag = False
        break
return False
```

The program will work without the `flag`s.

---

Comment: There is no need to check for `len(s) == 0` as, if it is the case, the for loop wouldn't execute and `len(stack)` would be `0`. Also, `if not stack:` inside the loop feels more pythonic.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger - Could you include this in an answer? This seems interesting.